# Tweet replies disappeaaring

Tags: twitter, notifications, reply

I'm making an application which automatically replies to certain tweets with **an image**. The image is tailored made for each tweet and the tweet is sent as a reply to the original tweet.

I'm using TwitterAPI python module. I'm tweeting with '**statuses/update**' end-point with '**in_reply_to_status_id**' and '**media_ids**'

The replies are showing in my timeline (since I'm tweeting) but not in the timeline of the recipient. Moreover, the notifications also disappear from recipient's account.

Further, the tweets are appearing in public search.

If anyone has clarity over this issue, please help. We need to urgently resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope, one thing that I know is that my tweets disappeared when I sent too much of tweets with media url and images. Also I used a genuine account rather than creating a test account which is not detected as bot by twitter. When I sent limited tweets iit was working.

Comment: Perhaps you are just hitting rate limits set by Twitter?  https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting

Comment: Same, i used real account to post tweets , i got alot of responds and suddenly 0 responds, i think twitter blocked my api request maybe?

Comment: @NishthaRai To find out why Twitter may be blocking you you should look at the returned status code and the returned error (if there is one)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the **@username** of the recipient within the `status` parameter (i.e. the body of the tweet reply), otherwise according to the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) the `in_reply_to_status_id` parameter will be ignored:

> This parameter will be ignored unless the author of the tweet this parameter references is mentioned within the status text. Therefore, you must include @username, where username is the author of the referenced tweet, within the update.

Comment: I have already used @username in the reply. It still doesn't work. What's weird is that the notification on the navbar shows an incoming notification but when i click on it... there's no notification at all (Not even the past notifications which were there a while ago). I can see the replies from the account I used to reply. Can't see it in the receipients account. :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, that is a common error and it seemed likely that would be your problem.  Can you post the exact request you are making (you can anonymise the user ID etc)?  Also, to confirm, are you using the Geduldig TwitterAPI from GitHub?  (https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)